# How to align two columns in Excel without losing alignment of third column

Tags: excel

I have three columns:

```
Key1   Value1     Key2
 1       50        9
 4       20        4 
 7       35        3
 9       45        1
 3       15
```

I want to align `Key1` and `Key2` in same row if they have same values and `Value1` should be changed according to `Key1`.

```
Key1   Value1     Key2
 9       45        9
 4       20        4 
 3       15        3
 1       50        1
 7       35
```

I don't have much knowledge of Excel functions so please suggest a direct formula to achieve this (if it's feasible).

Comment: Hi @Deepankar Singh, did this answer below help you with your problem?

Comment: Since I am newbie in this field, i didn't get most of it. I was trying to search something simple or a one liner formula for this. Anyway thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: As you learn Excel,  take a good look at the `VLOOKUP()` function, its the main way to reference data by a key in the first column of a data block. You will find it useful. VLOOKUP(lookup key, datablock, column I want from datablock, false for exact match)

Answer (score 1):

I thought of using Sort. You can set up a custom sort order in Excel like Jan, Feb, March,... but to do this for a range looks like you need VBA.

My formula below only works if the Key 2 is sorted in descending order. Not sure if this is just a quirk of your example. (But I am hoping to help and others can chip in.)

*STEP 1*

Assuming `Key1` above is in A1 in a new sheet. Insert a column before it called Sort and then add this formula in A2.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B2,$D$2:$D$6,1,FALSE)),NA(),MAX($D$2:$D$6)-$B2)
```

So you have.

```
Sort    Key1    Value1  Key2
8       1       50      9
5       4       20      4
#N/A    7       35      3
0       9       45      1
6       3       15
```

*STEP 2*

Select columns A B and C and **not D**. Go Data/Sort and use Sort order as your key.

*RESULT*

```
Sort    Key1    Value1  Key2
0       9       45      9
5       4       20      4
6       3       15      3
8       1       50      1
#N/A    7       35
```

**Explanation**

I use an `ISERROR` to mark items not in your `Key2` as Not Applicable (NA) so they drop out of sort. I then take maximum number in `Key2`, in this case the 9, and then subtract current value of number. Therefore 9 with sort value 0 bubbles to top.